# Scrapy - HTMLPathSelector, XPath, Extract

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using `Scrapy 0.16.5` for `Python 2.7` on `Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5`

I'm fairly new to `Scrapy`.  I've watched a handfull of tutorial videos and while that has been in some regards helpful, they haven't been able to definitively answer a number of questions I have which pertain to my current project- I haven't been able to find a solution which gets the data I need.

My project:

So I am working on putting together a scraper which goes to BoxOfficeMojo.com and gets 4 different things for each movie: the movie title, the movie URL, the date the movie was released and the amount of money grossed by the movie.  I then want to put this information into a MySQL database.  Initially, I'm just looking to get one single page of movies, specifically found [here](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/alphabetical.htm?letter=A&p=.html).  As you can see, this is only movies A-Ac.  Eventually I will need to get all of the A's and then all of the B's, etc.  But, for now, this will be good for building an initial scraper.

The Path:

So I can't really post the full path here, as it ends up just posting the movie information.  The xpath that leads to the data I'm interested in is:

```
  //div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]
  //div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table[2]
```

If you go to that page that I've linked to above and look at the source, follow the xpath, you will get to what I'm looking through.  The first part of that long string are links the the movie letters A-Z and then the movies on the current page and their info.

My code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from BoxOfficeMojo.items import BoxofficemojoItem

class MojoSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = 'MojoSpider'
   allowed_domains = ['boxofficemojo.com']
   start_urls = ['http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/alphabetical.htm?letter=A&p=.htm']

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    print ('hxs:', hxs)
    titles = hxs.select('//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]') #was previously
    print ('rows:', rows)
    for title in titles:
        print ('title:', title)
        movie = title.select('/tr')
        print ('movie', movie)

    #print ('title:', titles)
    items = [] #previously = []
    #for title in titles:
        #item = BoxofficemojoItem()
        #item['title'] = title.select('/td/font/b/text()').extract() #Was:td/font/a/b/text()
        #item['link'] = title.select('/td/font/b/a/@href').extract()     #Was:td/font/a/@href
        #item['gross'] = title.select('/td/font/text()').extract()  #Was:td[3]/font/text()
        #item['release'] = title.select('/td/a/text()').extract() #Was: td[7]/font/a/text()
        #items.append(item)
    #return items
```

NOTE:  I have commented out a number of things and added print statements in the hopes of figuring out what is going on.  The idea with the commented out section is that each item in the titles section would be a movie.

What is actually printed:

So here is what is actually printed out when the code is run

```
 ('row:', <HtmlXPathSelector     xpath='//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr' data=u'<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#dcdcdc"'>)
 ('cells:', [])
 ('row:', <HtmlXPathSelector   xpath='//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr' data=u'<tr><td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff"><'>)
 ('cells:', [])
 ('row:', <HtmlXPathSelector   xpath='//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr' data=u'<tr><td align="left" bgcolor="#f4f4ff"><'>)
 ('cells:', [])
 ('row:', <HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr' data=u'<tr><td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff"><'>)
 ('cells:', [])
 ('row:', <HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr' data=u'<tr><td align="left" bgcolor="#f4f4ff"><'>)
 ('cells:', [])
```

Again, this is just a minor selection.  Also, I had `row` instead of title when I was originally doing this- just wanted to make it more readable.

When I use commented out section, I always get a bunch of empty dictionary entries.

Answer (score 4):

Please type string() in place of text() it worked fine. I tested your code for one item. You can separate the rest.

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    print ('hxs:', hxs)
    titles = hxs.select('//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr/td') #was previously
    #print ('title:', titles)
    items = [] #previously = []
    for title in titles:
        item = OnthegoItem()
        item['title'] = title.select('string()').extract() #Was:td/font/a/b/text()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read through this and comment on it!  I will check and mark correct as soon as I can. Upvote for now though :-)!